# How to save PHP variables to a file?

Tags: php, shell

I have this script

```
<?php
include 'theme.php';
/*ceklogin();*/
css();
if($_POST['wget-send'])
    {
        $dir=$_POST['dir'];
        $link=$_POST['link'];
    exec('touch /root/wget/wget-download-link.txt',$out);
    exec('echo "'.$link.'" >> /root/wget/wget-download-link.txt',$out);
    exec('echo "'.$dir.'" > /root/wget/wget-dir.txt',$out);
        echo $out[2];
        exit();
    }
```

It's currently using shell to write contents to a file, my question is, how do you save the contents to a file with only PHP? since those shell scripts give me an error that I can't solve yet, I'd like to use only PHP to save contents to a file and get rid of the shell scripts. Please note that my contents consist of line breaks like this:

```
text1
text2
text3
```

and I want to keep the line breaks, which means I **don't** want them to be saved like this

```
text1 text2 text3
```

How do I do that?

Comment: Normally to save to a file you'd use `fopen` and `fwrite` not OS specific stuff like this.

Comment: You need to use `"\n"`

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [file_put_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) function.

Answer (score 1):

That code is pretty inefficient. There is **NO** point in firing up a shell just to echo some text out to a file. Why not:

```
file_put_contents('/root/wget/wget-download-link.txt', $link);
file_put_contents('/root/wget/wget-dir.txt', $dir);
```

For multiline/complicated text to output, just build it up in-ram:

```
   $text = 'foo';
   $text .= 'bar';
   $text .= long_ugly_generation_sequence();
   etc..
   file_put_contents(..., $text);
```